# togglebutton show state of service after leaving and return to activity

Tags: android, togglebutton

i have a mediaplayer that streams music in a service

in my main activity i click on a toggle button the music begins to stream and the image for the toggle button change from play to stop  when i leave my app the music stays playing  but when i return to the app the togglebutton is back to play i tried if statements but it doesnt work here is a example what i tried 
i tried this code in my service

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
MainActivity.playStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopbtn);    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Playbackservice create static variable isPlaying. Then in your activity onResume() use something like

```
onResume(){
if(Playbackservice.isPlaying){
   set toggle on
}else{
set toggle off
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. onResume that is the one i was looking for now i understand a littlebit more about the cycle Thanks Vandzi